# javascript comparing strings (for date purposes)

Tags: php, javascript

Ive only ever done absolute comparisons before, so Im a bit stuck as to how to deal with this...

I have two strings returned from PHP (format is DATE_ATOM i.e 2012-01-20)

What I need to do is compare one string (date) against another - however, I need to return true on the following three conditions

- The first date matches the second date (== got this one...)
- The first date matches the second date +1 day
- The first date matches the second date +2 days

Anything over that will return false.

How can I do this in as 'clean' a way as possible..

P.S This can be done in either PHP or Javascript - just the cleanest way possible would be prefered!!!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the full DATE_ATOM format? i.e. 2012-01-20T01:02:03+00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$first = strtotime($yourFirstDate);
$second = strtotime($yourSecondData);
if($first == $second OR $first == strtotime($yourSecondDate, "+1 day") OR $first == strtotime($yourSecondDate, "+2 days")) {
   echo "ok with date";
}
else {
  echo "out of range";
}
```

Comment: Perfect, clean and simple code. Many thanks. PHP is deffo the way to do this. I dont want to be splitting any variables in JS. Thanks :)

Comment: You have specified the strtotime arguments in the wrong order! it should be `strtotime("+1 day", $yourSecondDate)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a short way of doing it:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2012-03-20');
$datetime2=new DateTime('2012-03-18');

$intervalo = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$diferencia=$intervalo->format('%R%d');

if($diferencia>=0 && $diferencia<=2)
{
echo "OK";
}
```

The "%R" is important because it gives you if the difference is negative or positive, we only need positive, I have seen solutions that gives you OK but with negative values too.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer on php.net:

Object oriented style

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Procedural style

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

The above examples will output:

```
+2 days
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
var day = 86400000;  // milliseconds (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)

if ( Math.abs(new Date('2012-01-20') - new Date('2012-01-22')) <= 2 * day) {
  // dates are within 2 day of each other
}
```

Note that IE prior to version 8 does not like `new Date('2012-01-20')` and prefers `new Date('2012/01/20')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For **javascript** you can do this way:

```
function compareDates(date1, date2)
{
    date1 = date1.split('-').join('');
    date2 = date1.split('-').join('');

    if (date1 == date2)        {return true;}
    if (date1 == (+date2) + 1) {return true;}
    if (date1 == (+date2) + 2) {return true;}

    return false;
}

console.log( compareDates('2012-01-20', '2012-01-20') ); // true
console.log( compareDates('2012-01-21', '2012-01-20') ); // true
console.log( compareDates('2012-01-22', '2012-01-20') ); // true
console.log( compareDates('2012-01-23', '2012-01-20') ); // false
```

**EDITED A**
date can be now either in the format '2012-01-20T01:02:03+00:00' or '2012-01-20', thanks :) .. 
I don't know which format the user will use

```
function compareDates(date1, date2)
{
    date1 = date1.substring(0,10).split('-').join('');
    date2 = date2.substring(0,10).split('-').join('');

    if (date1 == date2)        {return true;}
    if (date1 == (+date2) + 1) {return true;}
    if (date1 == (+date2) + 2) {return true;}

    return false;
}

console.log( compareDates('2012-01-20T01:02:03+00:00', '2012-01-20') ); // true
console.log( compareDates('2012-01-21', '2012-01-20') ); // true
console.log( compareDates('2012-01-22', '2012-01-20T01:02:03+00:00') ); // true
console.log( compareDates('2012-01-23T01:02:03+00:00', '2012-01-20T01:02:03+00:00') ); // false
```

Comment: If he's really using DATE_ATOM (and not the date he provided in the question) this will not work. DATE_ATOM format is like: 2012-01-20T01:02:03+00:00